# .toString issue in IE

Tags: javascript, json, tostring

I have a form which submits a JSON object to Marketo for tracking registrations. There is a required hash function, which needs to be converted to a string.

```
hash.toString()
```

It seems that this is causing an issue in IE(the form values are not being submitted), but fine in Chrome and Firefox.

I am using json2.js to deal with older versions of IE.

Comment: You say hash is a function, so maybe you want `hash().toString()`? Or even just `hash()`?

Comment: Do you actually want the code from the function?

Comment: I should clarify: hash is a variable
    `var hash = CryptoJS.SHA1(message);`

Comment: so it's already a string...

Comment: The submission does not work without the `.toString()` function